# How to copy Excel values across?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy the data in table 1 to a new sheet and format it like
on table 2.

I am using below function which does half of the job.

```vb
Function csvRange(myRange As Range)
    Dim csvRangeOutput
    Dim entry as variant
    For Each entry In myRange
        If Not IsEmpty(entry.Value) Then
            csvRangeOutput = csvRangeOutput & entry.Value & ","
        End If
    Next
    csvRange = Left(csvRangeOutput, Len(csvRangeOutput) - 1)
End Function
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Join Data

- `JoinData` is the recommended solution with some 'error handling'.
- `JoinDataShort` is the same without any error handling.
- Adjust the values in the constants section before using them.
- Both of the mentioned procedures use the remaining three procedures.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub joinData()
    
    ' Source
    Const srcName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const srcCols As String = "A:B"
    Const srcLastRowCol As Long = 2
    Const srcFirstRow As Long = 1
    ' Destination
    Const dstName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dstFirst As String = "D1"
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Source
    Dim rng As Range
    With wb.Worksheets(srcName)
        Set rng = defRangeFrLrc(.Columns(srcCols), srcFirstRow, srcLastRowCol)
    End With
    If rng Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Data
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = getDelimited(rng)
    If IsEmpty(Data) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Destination
    Dim isWritten As Boolean
    With wb.Worksheets(dstName)
        isWritten = writeDataToRange(.Range(dstFirst), Data, True)
    End With
    
    ' Information
    If isWritten Then
        MsgBox "Data transferred.", vbInformation, "Success"
    Else
        MsgBox "An error occurred.", vbCritical, "Fail"
    End If

End Sub

' Compare with 'joinData' to understand what can go wrong.
Sub joinDataShort()
    
    ' Source
    Const srcName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const srcCols As String = "A:B"
    Const srcLastRowCol As Long = 2
    Const srcFirstRow As Long = 1
    ' Destination
    Const dstName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dstFirst As String = "D1"
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Source
    Dim rng As Range
    With wb.Worksheets(srcName)
        Set rng = defRangeFrLrc(.Columns(srcCols), srcFirstRow, srcLastRowCol)
    End With
    
    ' Data
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = getDelimited(rng)
    
    ' Destination
    writeDataToRange wb.Worksheets(dstName).Range(dstFirst), Data, True
    
End Sub

Function defRangeFrLrc( _
    rng As Range, _
    Optional ByVal FirstRow As Long = 1, _
    Optional ByVal LastRowColumn As Long = 1) _
As Range
    On Error GoTo clearError
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        Dim cel As Range
        With rng
            Set cel = .Columns(LastRowColumn) _
                .Resize(.Rows.Count - FirstRow + 1).Offset(FirstRow - 1).Find( _
                    What:="*", _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
            If Not cel Is Nothing Then
                Set defRangeFrLrc = .Resize(cel.Row - FirstRow + 1) _
                    .Offset(FirstRow - 1)
            End If
        End With
    End If
ProcExit:
    Exit Function
clearError:
    Resume ProcExit
End Function

Function getDelimited( _
    rng As Range, _
    Optional ByVal Delimiter As String = ",") _
As Variant
    On Error GoTo clearError
    ' Arrays
    With rng.Columns(1)
        Dim rCount As Long
        rCount = .Rows.Count - Application.CountBlank(.Offset)
        Dim Data As Variant: Data = .Resize(, 2).Value
    End With
    Dim sCount As Long: sCount = UBound(Data, 1)
    Dim Result() As String: ReDim Result(1 To rCount, 1 To 2)
    ' Headers
    Result(1, 1) = Data(1, 1)
    Result(1, 2) = Data(1, 2)
    ' Body
    Dim arl As Object: Set arl = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    Dim i As Long
    Dim k As Long: k = 1
    Dim cIndex As Long: cIndex = 1
    Dim doAdd As Boolean
    For i = 2 To sCount
        If Len(Data(i, 1)) > 0 Then
            If i > 2 Then
                Result(cIndex, 2) = Join(arl.ToArray, Delimiter)
                arl.Clear
            End If
            k = k + 1
            cIndex = k
            Result(k, 1) = Data(i, 1)
        End If
        arl.Add Data(i, 2)
    Next i
    Result(cIndex, 2) = Join(arl.ToArray, Delimiter)
    ' Result
    getDelimited = Result
ProcExit:
    Exit Function
clearError:
    Resume ProcExit
End Function

Function writeDataToRange( _
        FirstCellRange As Range, _
        Data As Variant, _
        Optional ByVal ClearToBottom As Boolean = False, _
        Optional ByVal ClearWorksheet As Boolean = False) _
As Boolean
    On Error GoTo clearError
    With FirstCellRange.Resize(, UBound(Data, 2))
        If ClearWorksheet Then
            .Worksheet.Cells.Clear
        Else
            If ClearWorksheet Then
                .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1).Clear
            End If
        End If
        .Resize(UBound(Data, 1)).Value = Data
    End With
    writeDataToRange = True
ProcExit:
    Exit Function
clearError:
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple code which should work for you. See the comments and edit them to suit your needs.

```
Public Sub RearrangeData()
    Dim rngSource As Range, rng As Range
    Dim lngOutRow As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    '\\ Set Source Range
    Set rngSource = Range("A2:B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    lngOutRow = 1 '\\Define Output Row
    For Each rng In rngSource.Columns(1).Cells
        If Len(rng.Value) > 0 Then
            lngOutRow = lngOutRow + 1
            Range("C" & lngOutRow).Value = rng.Value '\\Define Output Column 1
        End If
        If Len(rng.Offset(0, 1).Value) > 0 Then
            If Len(Range("D" & lngOutRow).Value) = 0 Then
                Range("D" & lngOutRow).Value = rng.Offset(0, 1).Value '\\Define Output Column 2
            Else
                Range("D" & lngOutRow).Value = Range("D" & lngOutRow).Value & "," & rng.Offset(0, 1).Value '\\Define Output Column 2
            End If
        End If
    Next rng
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```